# Added scheme to LSApplicationQueriesSchemes but canOpenURL still fails

Tags: ios, swift

Please help! Why am i still getting not allowed to query for scheme despite including the scheme in the LSApplicationQueriesSchemes?

My class:

```
class LearningBotScreen: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func googleAssistantOpenButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        let googleAssistantUrl = URL(string:"youtube://")!

        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(googleAssistantUrl){
            print("opening");
            UIApplication.shared.open(googleAssistantUrl)
            /*UIApplication.shared.open(googleAssistantUrl!, options:[:], completionHandler: nil)*/
        }
        else{
            print("download app")
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "http://apps.apple.com/sg/app/id1220976145")!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            }


}
```

My `info.plist`:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd"> <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>instagram</string>
        <string>youtube</string>
    </array>
    <key>LSApplicationCategoryType</key>    <string></string>    
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>   <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>      
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>   <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>    
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>    <string>6.0</string>     
    <key>CFBundleName</key>     <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>     
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>  <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_PACKAGE_TYPE)</string>      
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>   <string>1.0</string>     
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>  <string>1</string> </dict> </plist>
```

[image: The error message]

> 2019-12-17 15:58:08.426142+0800 drmorpheus[1000:203271] -canOpenURL:
>   failed for URL: "youtube://" - error: "This app is not allowed to
>   query for scheme youtube" download app

[image: updated code]

Comment: That's your UI tests info.plist. What does your app's info.plist look like?

Comment: Hi thanks so much for answering!! Good catch! It was indeed missing in my app's info.plist. I added it in, but it doesn't seem to work still >< Gives the same error. Let me upload the new screenshot

Comment: Hmmm, that's really weird. I'm not really sure why it's still giving you that error. Maybe try deleting your app from your device and reinstall it? Apparently `canOpenURL` can only be called 50 times by your app, according to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622952-canopenurl): "If your app is linked against an earlier version of iOS but is running in iOS 9.0 or later, you can call this method up to 50 times. After reaching that limit, subsequent calls always return false. If the user reinstalls or upgrades the app, iOS resets the limit."

Comment: Thank you!! I managed to fix it. I think it was something to do with the info.plist in my app that you told me :D I rebuilt project and it works!

Answer (score 1):

You've edited the info.plist that belongs to your UI tests target, not your app target. Add the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` entry to your app's info.plist instead.